# Which ORM can preserve the correspondence between db schema and domain model?

Tags: .net, orm

It is the common case when domain model is changed during project development. If db schema is generated from domain model, then the following problem appears. When I change model, I need to change schema also. I am searching for the ORM which can do such changes automatically (or, semi-automatically).

At least, the ORM must support the following changes:

- Renaming of a class
- Renaming of a property or a field
- Removing of a property or a field

Answer (score 2):

The Mindscape LightSpeed O/R Mapper supports this.

[Mindscape LightSpeed O/R Mapper](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/LightSpeed/default.aspx)

Includes model refactoring tools also so if you change the name of a field in the domain model it will rename all references to it also.

Along with this it also provides the ability to one click update your domain model with database changes, or update your database with model changes meaning you can add properties/fields + classes/tables easily.

Answer (score 0):

[ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework) supports all you want

Answer (score 0):

It seems MS going to release Entity Framework v2. IMHO, they will have some support for this.

Comment: Appears DataObjects.NET ORM have same ability (found at theirs wiki http://wiki.dataobjects.net/index.php?title=Schema_upgrade). You should know it's developed by russian company :)